# Check if each value within list is present in the given Django Model Table in a SINGLE query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

So let's say I want to implement this generic function:

```py
def do_exist(key:str, values:list[any], model: django.db.models.Model) -> bool
```

Which checks if all the given values exist within a given model's column named `key` in a SINGLE query.
I've implemented something like this

```py
from django.db.models import Exists
def do_exist(key, values, model):
    chained_exists = (Exists(model.objects.filter(F(key)=value)) for value in values)
    qs = model.objects.filter(*chained_exists).values("pk")[:1] 
    # Limit and values used for the sake of less payload
    return len(qs) > 0
```

It generates a pretty valid SQL query, but the thing that scares me is that if I try to append evaluating method call to `qs` like `.first()` instead of `[:1]` or `.exists()` MYSQL connection drops.
Does anyone have a more elegant way of solving this?

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure if I understand your question, but if you want to filter In Django, you can use the id__in query with a queryset to filter down a queryset based on a list of IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know you're passing in `N` pks, then a `count()` query filtered by those pks should have exactly `N` results.

```
def do_exist(model, pks):
    return model.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).count() == len(pks)
```

Comment: And how about fields that are NOT Unique?

Comment: Primary keys are always unique. That'd be a different question. However, for non-unique values, you could add `.distinct()` before `.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=pks)
```

This gives you a queryset that you can apply .all() etc to

Comment: Your count can always be done at the end of the query but you stated that your problem was evaluating your queries with .all()

Answer (score 0):

```
res = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=pks)
```

Comment: Read it again but slowly